# How can I use omniauth-facebook for iOS facebook login

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, facebook, omniauth

I have rails server side who have omniauth-facebook authentication gem on it.
I want to login with facebook using omniauth-facebook (facebook ios SDK alterntive) but I dont know how to get user auth details and close inAppBrowser when the user facebook login end.
Thanks